# Tuning peg tight on a guitar (possibly slipping, too)

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings

So my guitar's G-string peg is feeling tight. I'm a newbie, but I think that the peg is slipping, since I can hear a click sound when I try tuning it up. The G string is now around 2 whole steps behind G, yet it feels tight. Please tell me what I should do now?

Edit 1: Sorry for posting this late, but... https://vimeo.com/467097345

If you watch the video you'll hear the sound. It's a fender squier acoustic guitar.

Edit 2:
[image: the back side of the head]

Comment: Do your tuners have exposed gears or are they sealed? If they are exposed make sure that the gear is seated properly on the shaft and that the screw that holds it in place is not loose.

Comment: Adding a picture or two of your headstock would answer some questions we have, so we can answer yours more easily?

Comment: Without relevant information, such as what sort of guitar, what sort of strings, this is not going to get a good answer.

Comment: They're sealed, but i took them out and checked what was wrong. They're normal pegs. I'm not sure what the problem is. Please check out the link which I've added. You might under the issue then.

Comment: They're not pegs, they're geared tuners. Different behaviors.

Comment: Oops okay Sorry. Thanks! Understand* Also, please check out the video which shows the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without more info we can only guess:

1. If the string is slipping it will go down in pitch quickly while tuning or playing. If that happens, the best thing to do is to unwind it, remove the string from the peg, and put it back properly. If you're not sure how to do that, look online for some instructional videos on how to install strings correctly, so they can't slip.
2. Could it be that the wrong string is there? If a thicker strings ended up there by mistake, it may be impossible to tune, it will either break or not go beyond a certain point.
3. If the machine heads are old and worn, or cheap and poorly made, hardness and imprecision are to be expected. One thing you can try is to loosen it up, put a couple of drops of oil in it, make it go back and forth one time to spread the oil everywhere, and then try to tune the string again.
4. If it's a classical guitar, there'll be a screw that keeps the gear head locked into the white plastic pin, and (in some models) it also controls how tight the peg is when you turn it. So make sure it is tight enough to keep the gear solid with the plastic peg, but not so extremely tight that it makes the machine head impossibly hard to use.
5. Some electric guitar pegs have a locking screw or metal gear that you can tighten with your hands to keep the tuning locked in place for a longer time than usual. In such a case you may have to loosen the locking screw/gear a bit, before you can tune the string normally again.

Comment: I have uploaded a video which shows what the issue is. The peg is too tight and i can hear the sound from the video often.